# Using :Before and :After to add images to the end of my navigation?

Tags: html, css

Wondering if this is the best method to add an image to the beginning and end of my navigation. As it stands my navigation looks like this:

[image]

But realistically I would like to add this corner piece to the edges of it:

[image]

Here is my CSS of me trying to implement it:

```
#menu-top {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 -10px 0;
    padding:.25em 0 0;
    border-width:0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    background: url( http://www.leaguememe.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Horizontalbannermiddletop.png );

    min-height:50px;
}
#menu-top:before {
    content:'';
    z-index: 20;
    background: url( http://www.leaguememe.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Horizontaltop_left.png );
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    /* bottom:-5px; */
    bottom: 0px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    display:block;
    border-color:transparent #222 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px 10px 5px 0;
}
#menu-top:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:-5px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    display:block;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #222;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0 0 5px 10px;
}
#menu-top ul {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:.5em 30px;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}
#menu-top ul:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:4px;
    left:-5px;
    width: 34px;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    background: url( http://www.leaguememe.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Horizontaltop_left.png );
}
#menu-top ul:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:4px;
    right:-5px;
    width:27px;
    height:39px;
    display:block;
}
#menu-top li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0 .25em 1em;
    padding:0;
    line-height:2.5em;
}
#menu-top li a {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #e9d6d6;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    outline: 0;
    padding: .45em .6em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition: background-color, -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}
#menu-top li a:hover,
#menu-top li a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Am I getting the use of :Before and :After wrong?

Comment: You won't be able to see the background images when your pseudoelements are 0x0 in dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this a number of ways, including the use of pseudoelements. In the following, I placed two elements at the top left, and top right of my `nav` element. I then assigned the new background image, and flipped the element to the right so it mirrors that on the left:

```css
nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 703px; height: 45px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMV59.png");
}

nav::before, nav::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 95px; height: 50px;
    position: absolute; top: -8px; left: -5px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqsBV.png");
}

nav::after {
    left: auto; right: -5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

I should note that the `transform` property was only used because you provided the left corner image only. This property is not going to be supported in Internet Explorer 8 (which does support `:before` and `:after`). If you'd like the above to support IE8, you'll need to abandon the `transform`, and instead provide a different background for the `:after` pseudoelement.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NXP3g/1/